# Connect a database of amazon ec2 instance with another ec2 instance

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two ec2 instances running laravel projects using ubuntu 20.04 on both instances. Both instances are running fine.
One instance contains a database which is also working with one project but I want the same database to connect with the other laravel project while sitting in other EC2 instance. So here is what I means.

2 EC2 instances (Ubuntu 20.04). Let's call them (Instance A & Instance B)

Instance A has mysql database up and running and connected to the laravel project

Instance B also required to use database of Instance A. I did it on digitalocean but I am not finding any solution on internet.
Any help would be really appreciated

Thank You

Comment: Instance A needs to allow inbound MySQL access from instance B so modify the security group of instance A to allow ingress on TCP port 3306 from the security group of instance B.

Comment: Databases do not "connect" to apps. Rather, the apps connect to the database. What have you tried so far, and what problem are you facing?

Comment: @jarmod security group is same for each of the instance

Comment: Even though both instances are in the same SG, that won't allow communication from one instance to the other. Add an rule to the security group that allows ingress from itself i.e. from the security group itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with instances security groups.

All I had to do was to allow MySQL to listen to connections from remote IP addresses, and for that, I created a new user in MySQL that listens to the connection from the second ip address.

```sql
CREATE USER 'new_remote_user'@'ip-address-of-your-instance' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass-of-new-instance';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'new_remote_user'@'ip-address-of-your-instance';
```